# Draft js replaceText remove inlineStyles

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, draftjs

I implement WYSIWYG editor with draftjs and I have a set of rules for typography fixing. I use `Modifier.replaceText` to replace what I want, but the problem is, when I call it, it removes inlineStyles in replaced text.

Here is a block of code that I use for typography. Inputs are rules (array with rules) and editorState.

```js
rules.forEach(({ toReplace, replace }) => {
   const blockToReplace = [];
   let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
   const blockMap = contentState.getBlockMap();

   blockMap.forEach(contentBlock => {
      const text = contentBlock.getText();
      let matchArr;

      while ((matchArr = toReplace.exec(text)) !== null) {
         const start = matchArr.index;
         const end = start + matchArr[0].length;
         const blockKey = contentBlock.getKey();
         const blockSelection = SelectionState.createEmpty(blockKey).merge({
            anchorOffset: start,
            focusOffset: end,
         });

         blockToReplace.push(blockSelection);
      }
   });

   blockToReplace.reverse().forEach((selectionState) => {
      contentState = Modifier.replaceText(
         contentState,
         selectionState,
         text.replace(search, replace)
      );
    });

    editorState = EditorState.push(editorState, contentState);
});
```

So, my input is: `*bold...*`

The wrong output is: `*bold*…`

Should be: `*bold…*`

*Note: asterisks are for bold designation, change is three dots to horizontal ellipsis (U+2026)*

Anybody any idea? I google it for two days and nothing...

Comment: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier/#replacetext did you read the doc? you need pass style and entity argument.

Comment: @JiangYD Yes, I read it, actually, I try it but it does not work as I need. Doc is really simple, there is no doc about how `DraftInlineStyle` works and what I need for it, or how I get it in the first place. I don't mention `entityKey`, what is this, what it is for?

I found this https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/2073 but there is no answer.

Then I found some examples here https://javascript.hotexamples.com/examples/draft-js/Modifier/replaceText/javascript-modifier-replacetext-method-examples.html but there are no descriptions.

Comment: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-character-metadata/#applyentity and https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-inline-styles

Comment: The official doc not helping as I say... But looks like [this](https://javascript.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xf246c1ffbcf6d09f655f81a97a9de5912ef7c6a990735b2856adde341d34a96e&fullName=draft-js-master/src/component/handlers/editOnInput.js&project=facebook/draft-js) works

Comment: @JiangYD can you provide some examples? Because the doc has one sentence for things and not helping at all. The solution that I found works in some cases and I need just preserver inline formatting...

Comment: for working code example, you may try freelancer.com not stackoverflow.com

Comment: if you don't want to help, please don't help at all
I ask for help because the doc is not helping and googling doesn't help at all...

Comment: I did help in real. Because I implemented the same function in my application by the functions I paseted. Your code missing the style argument in replaceText function, that's the problem.